# MYSql query to find booking available in hotel management system

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a sample project "Hotel Management System". Here I have created two tables.

tbl_room

|**roomid**|**roomno**|

and

tbl_booking

|**bookingid**|**roomid**|**checkin**|**checkout**|

I have created a query 
I get $indate and $outdate from the form.

```
$sql="SELECT roomid from tbl_room 
      where tbl_room.roomid not in (select roomid from tbl_booking where
      checkout>'$indate' )";
```

This query doesn't work. It only checks the checkout date and i cannot book the previous date.

Comment: Why don't you try checking like this where checkout between '$indate' and '$outdate' this will help you in understanding if rooms are not booked for the given date

Comment: I tried to do like that :  $sql="SELECT roomid from tbl_room where tbl_room.roomid not in (select roomid from tbl_booking where 
checkout between '$checkin' and '$checkout' )";
  It replies shows all the booked rooms at the time.    It shows following query ::    SELECT roomid from tbl_room where tbl_room.roomid not in (select roomid from tbl_booking where checkout between '2017-12-06' and '2017-12-09' )

Comment: What is the desired out put you are expecting ?

Comment: I want to show the rooms which are not booked during the time period.

Comment: please find my answer, make sure your php code date format are correct.

Comment: Here is the Details::: $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE roomid not in (SELECT b.roomid FROM tbl_booking b where (b.checkout BETWEEN '$checkin' and '$checkout'))";
echo $sql;                           after running the code::::  SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE roomid not in (SELECT b.roomid FROM tbl_booking b where (b.checkout BETWEEN '2017-12-09' and '2017-12-12'))    and again it displays all the data. Suppose i have booked a room no 101 for december 1 to 5 then other person had booked same room for 10 to 15 again if i have entered date december 8 to 12 then it shows all the rooms.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE roomid not in (SELECT b.roomid FROM tbl_booking b 
 where(b.checkout BETWEEN '$checkin' and '$checkout') and 
 (b.checkin BETWEEN '$checkin' and '$checkout'))";
```

Finally, This query Worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check this query, it checks if the given date range has entries in the booking table and excludes them from room_master.

`$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE roomid not in (SELECT b.roomid FROM tbl_booking b where(b.checkout BETWEEN '$checkin' and '$checkout') and (b.checkin BETWEEN '$checkin' and '$checkout'))";`